# Is there a way to update the cell adjacent to the cell I searched for using .find in gspread api for python

Tags: python, gspread

I am trying to use the .find feature in gspread to locate a cell and update the cell next to it.

I have some python code that makes use of gspread api.  The Google Sheet has columns Name and Color.  I am able to use the .find feature to search for the cell that holds the name "Joe" however I need to update the cell next to the cell "Joe" in the column Colors with another variable called 'color'.

```
#Define the variables
name = 'Joe'
color = 'Blue'

# Search the google sheet to find the location of the cell named 'Joe'
sheet.find(name)
# Update the cell next to the location of the cell named 'Joe' with the color variable.
sheet.update(name, color)
```

I realise that sheet.update(name,color) is incorrect but not sure how else to express what I'm trying to do.  I have checked the gspread documentation however I have had no luck.  Perhaps there is another way I could achieve this result that im not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put a value of `color` to the next cell of the `name`.

  - About `the cell next to the location of the cell named 'Joe'`, when `Joe` is "B2", you want to put the value of `color` to "C2".
- You have already been able to update cells using gspread.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, from the returned value from `sheet.find(name)`, the coordinate is retrieved. Then, `color` is put using `update_cell()`.

#### Modified script:

```
name = 'Joe'
color = 'Blue'

cell = sheet.find(name)  # Modified
sheet.update_cell(cell.row, cell.col + 1, color)  # Modified
```

#### Note:

- When `Joe` is "B2", if you want to put the value of `color` to "B1", please use the following script.

  - `sheet.update_cell(cell.row - 1, cell.col, color)`
- When `Joe` is "B2", if you want to put the value of `color` to "B3", please use the following script.

  - `sheet.update_cell(cell.row + 1, cell.col, color)`
- When `Joe` is "B2", if you want to put the value of `color` to "A2", please use the following script.

  - `sheet.update_cell(cell.row, cell.col - 1, color)`

#### References:

- [find(query)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=find#gspread.models.Worksheet.find)
- [update_cell(row, col, value)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_cell#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cell)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, I’m going to try this when I get back to my computer and update you. Thank you so much and yes you were understanding me correctly.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for the answer, it resolved my issue perfectly.  I was attempting to break the results from .find into a string and increate the last digit by one.  Your way is much cleaner.  Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.